# mongodb not asking for authentication in authentication enabled mode

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb and was trying authentication in mongod. I tried following:

1. started mongod in normal mode added users, verfied users are there
2. started mongod --auth
   server log say authentication is enabled .
3. open compass or mongo , I observed it is opening dbs without asking for any password.
   **UPDATE:** if i stop MongoDB service, authentication work on starting dont work

   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin>mongod --auth
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.411+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.413+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.723+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.723+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.724+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.724+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.725+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.726+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":6072,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"SDIN-SWT-NDT-121"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.726+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.726+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.3","gitVersion":"657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.726+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19042)"}}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.726+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"security":{"authorization":"enabled"}}}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.727+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.728+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=32174M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.823+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635110439:822647][6072:140734753232208], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 10 through 11"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.873+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635110439:873197][6072:140734753232208], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 11 through 11"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.921+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635110439:921070][6072:140734753232208], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 10/13696 to 11/256"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:39.997+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635110439:997804][6072:140734753232208], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 10 through 11"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.066+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635110440:66588][6072:140734753232208], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 11 through 11"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.107+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635110440:107481][6072:140734753232208], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.108+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635110440:107481][6072:140734753232208], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.109+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635110440:109476][6072:140734753232208], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 8748"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.201+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":473}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.201+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.206+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.209+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.267+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip  to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.269+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.269+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.272+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.412+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.415+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
   {"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T02:50:40.416+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}

[image: mongo showing no authorization]

[image: added users]

[image]

//mongodb config

#net:

port: 27017
bindIp: 127.0.0.1

#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Are you sure you run the same mongod process? Check with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` and/or `db.hello()`

Comment: what do you mean - `UPDATE: if i stop MongoDB service, authentication work on starting dont work`?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @barrypicker  If mongod is running and i stop mongoDB service in task manager, and then run mongo shell, it is running in authenticated mode, but as soon as i start service again db again get in to un authenticated mode, i.e., i can access it without any password from compass

Comment: if you stop the service then how can the server be running in auth mode?  There must be another `mongod` process running somewhere on your computer.  Look at all your running processes and kill the offending `mongod` process, or reboot your computer, then disable the service.

Comment: please paste the `mongod.conf` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable access control:

a.    If you start the mongod from the command line, add the `--auth` command line option:

```
mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

b. If you start the mongod using a configuration file, add the `security.authorization` configuration file setting:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

Comment: I hav tried that, but adding authorization: enabled, make mongodb service crash and it wont run again, though mongod and mongo works

Comment: @murmansk  do you mean the problem is when you try to start the service through service' vs running `mongod -f mongod.conf` ?

if so, the problem sounds like it's related to the way you installed mongodb on your environment.

Comment: After making changes to config if I restart  machine then service does not run. Service definitely look like cause as in stopper state , if i run mongod and mongo, it starts in authenticated mode, but then it wont be accessible in network, so running service is also essential

Comment: Looks like reason service was failing was due to some extra spaces in authentication field, now mongod automatically starts in auth mode. Though still puzzled why --auth does not work while config change works.